# Under the hood of Java application servers resources

Tags: java, java-ee

We are used to Node.js / Python / Insert X.

Moving to a Java EE stack, it seems to me like all of the resources are 'press this button', 'do that' without any actual architectural explanation.

For the time being I'm interested in answers to the following questions (I'm completely ignorant on the topic, so some of them may sound stupid):

1. How does the Rest-API fit into the picture? It seems like EE Servers don't implement them themselves, so one has to use Jenkins. What is it? How does the server understand how to reroute requests to the 'Jenkins classes'
2. How are these 'Jenkins classes' handled? Does the server create a new thread for each request?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is actually a CI tool, did you mean JAX-RS? That's the Java API for RESTful web services. There's an introductory tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html).

The way it works is you have to provide an implementation of the JAX-RS API ([Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) is the reference implementation, it may be installed with your server or available as an add-on). Once that is in place, you simply define a servlet mapping that directs service requests to the JAX-RS servlet. That servlet then takes care of figuring out how to direct it to the implementation classes that service the particular request.